# Sublimetext3 Building with Lua (windows)

Tags: lua, sublimetext3

I'm having difficulty building using lua in sublimetext3, this is how set up my system: using a sublimetext3 lua environment and build system on a *.lua file. I keep receiving this error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['lua', 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\SublimeText3\\LuaWorkspace\\helloworld.lua']]
[dir: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\SublimeText3\LuaWorkspace]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\LOVE;C:\Progra~1\Lua\5.3.4_64;C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
[Finished]
```

and this is what my lua.sublime_build file looks like:

```
{
    "cmd": ["lua", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(?:lua:)?[\t ](...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.lua"
}
```

I can get this to work fine using a cmd prompt with lua *.lua however it would be nice to do it straight from sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue after some digging and researching... the problem was how lua was being found; my fix was to place a .bat file within the path folder that helps find the lua53 command:

Innards of the .bat file:

```
@"%~dp0lua53.exe" %*
```

Changes to the lua.sublime_build file:

```
"cmd": ["lua.bat", "$file"]
```

all other lines can remain the same.

Comment: Can you explain this? Your original error is caused by windows not being able to find the `lua` command to execute; did you just create a batch file and put it somewhere on the path?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the process a bit better